# Core Location - Get distance Range

Tags: iphone

I need to identify coordinates for the range selected by User. I can get users current coordinates by coreLocation but I need to pick places of interest in user selected value range say 1 mile within his current location. Essentially I want to circle around 1 mile coordinates. 
Any help/lead would really be appreciated, I am new to iPhone programming.